# Can I save pasted image to last used directory in Lyx?

Tags: graphics, lyx

I save figures in ./fig folder. While every time I paste an image, the file dialog always opens ./ folder for me, then I have to select ./fig folder and rename the image file. Can I make it default to open ./fig everytime it saves image so that I don' t have to rename everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no native way in LyX to do this. There is a feature request being made (at http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7809).

If you happen to be on Linux (probably also works for others but not sure how) you could make a keyboard shortcut that would do this. What the shortcut would do is copy from the clipboard to a specified folder (easy if you are using [copyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) for example), then use [LyXServer](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXServer) to execute a command like

```
inset-insert graphics filename /path/to/file/file.png
```